# What is the correct syntax for using EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS?

Tags: doxygen

I have a class like so:

```
class Foo {
public:
  /** blah blah */
  void bar();
}
```

I want to exclude this from the documentation, but `EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS` isn't working for me. I have tried the following (one by one):

```
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS = Foo::bar
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS = Foo::*
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS = Foo
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS = *
```

None of these is working. Is there a mistake in my syntax, or is there some other configuration I need to change for this to take effect?

I have looked at several questions on SO, but the syntax used in those answers doesn't work for me.

Comment: That syntax looks right according to the manual.  Are you actually testing the question with that code or is that just an illustration for the question.  I ask because if, in reality, you have multiple entries on the line, beware the separator (e.g. comma) between entries can be different between doxyfile comment and doxyfile syntax (FILE_PATTERNS, for example, shows _commas_ in the description, but needs spaces - _and doesn't work with commas._)

Comment: Good point, and I was not aware of that issue. I have tried with a single entry as well (no separators), but doesn't work. Let me try a few more experiments.

Comment: Alright, I did another experiment with the exact same code and config I have posted in this question, and it still isn't working for me.

Comment: I'm out of ideas now :-(  What version of Doxygen are you using?  If it's not the latest, does updating make any difference?  (OK, so it's unlikely).

Comment: I got exactly the same issue, @MaskedMan. Did you eventually get to solve it?

Comment: @FabioA. I don't remember what I eventually did with it. I have since moved on from that job, so I cannot go back and check. :(

Comment: Nevermind, solved it. Apparently I had to also add the name of the namespace alone, without scope operator. Or so it seems. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

This exclude expression works good in my case with doxygen 1.8.14:

```
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS = "TestTemplate< T, std::string >" "TestNS::*" "TestClass*"
```

In EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS it is specified or exact symbol name or a '*'-pattern. Exact symbol name may be retrieved from doxygen XML output (try enable it in Doxyfile).